# Amazon S3 upload Image from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm uploading the image using aws-s3 gem, it uploads perfectly and give me the url. Image is in PNG format but when I hit the public url in my browser, it starts downloading, but I don't want to download it, I want to see the image in browser.

Please tell me if you know which parameter in the following request should be added for this or what change is required to achieve this?

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store(base_name,open(local_file),bucket,:content_type => mime_type,:access => :public_read,:authenticated => false)

s3_url = AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(params[:name],bucket)[/[^?]+/]
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a browser thing? Do other png's display as desired?

Comment: @umair  i have just tried your code with my app, and it works perfectly, when i click the link the image gets loaded in my browser. Also since you are uploading with :access => :public_read, add this to the s3_url, s3_url = AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(params[:name],bucket, :authenticated => false)[/[^?]+/], which is suggested by s3 docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `:content_type => mime_type` if `mime_type` is correct.

Comment: here , mime_type is mime_type = "application/octet-stream"